# Add Increasing Numbers to Beginning of FileName in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a set of files in a folder, all pdfs.  There is no uniform name to the documents, but I would like each one to be proceeded by a number, followed by an underscore, then "TAB."  In other words, I want it to look like this:

1.01_TAB "fsfsdFSDF"

2.01_TAB "sjfsdjfsd"

etc.

Can someone help with this?   Here's what I have so far:

$x=1

Dir *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $x+ $*.BaseName+ $*.Extension; -f $x++}

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a renaming tool. There are a lot of different ones out there. I like [Advanced Renamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/).

Comment: What I have so far:  

$x=1
Dir *.pdf  | Rename-Item -NewName { $x+ $_.BaseName+ $_.Extension; -f $x++}

Comment: My apologies: I wasn't aware of the conventions of the forum.  I cannot download other renaming tools, since my workplace has administrative requirements for functions like that.

Answer (score 1):

I;m guessing you didn't actually want quotes around the original filenames. Try the following code. In my testing, $i won't increment inside the 'Newname' scriptblock unless it's a reference variable. With the -WhatIf parameter, you can safely test the code:

```
$i = [ref]1
gci *.pdf | rename-item -NewName {'{0}.01_TAB {1}' -f $i.value++, $_.Name} -whatif
```

Keith

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder" -Filter *.txt
$x = 1

ForEach ($originalFile in $originalFiles) {
    Rename-Item -Path $originalFile.FullName -NewName (($originalFile.Directory.FullName) + "\" + $x + $originalFile.Name)
    $x++
}
```

Definitely not my best work... may well revise this after I've had coffee - but it seems to do what you need it to.

[image]